# What rock layer is beneath the Vishnu Basement Rock in the Grand Canyon?

Tags: geology, regional-geology, bedrock

I read that the deepest part of the Grand Canyon that we can see are the Vishnu Basement Rocks, deposited 2 billion years ago (according to the Grand Canyon Wikipedia page). But what kind of rock lies beneath the Vishnu rock layer? The Grand Canyon is a mile deep, but continental crust is tens of miles thick. What makes up the remainder?